# javascript $(document).on('click') doesn't work in html

Tags: html, document

Here is my .html code file below, it doesn't seem toload the click function at all..have I missed anything?

I am new to this, any help for this would be great!!

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1> hello </h1>
    <audio id="audio">
    <source src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1538714/article_resources/song.ogg"     type="audio/aac">
    </audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
function dosomething(){
    $('body').append('document click<br />');
    document.getElementById('audio').play();};
    $(document).on('click', function(){dosomething()});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check with below answer , you have missed jQuery library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add jQuery library first

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <h1> hello </h1>
    <audio id="audio">
    <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40410302/rainbowride.aac"     type="audio/aac">
    </audio>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function dosomething(){
    $('body').append('document click<br />');
    document.getElementById('audio').play();};
    $(document).on('click', function(){dosomething()});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @2060754z please tick the answer if its worked for you

Comment: I WILL after the time limit :-)